# Is it possible to revert to previous version after uploading the new version of app in android market?

Tags: android, version, upgrade, google-play

I have uploaded an upgrade of some app in android market. Now I want to revert to previous version. Means I do not want people to download the new version but they should be allowed to download only the previous version. Is there some way....???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have published a new of the application, then you can deactivate the new version and reactivate the old version of the application. This is allowed by the Google Play. You need to select "switch to advanced mode".

Comment: you can no longer re-activate the older version -it gives you an error

Comment: There was a change in Google Play's policy since 1 October 2012, so may be this is limited since that period. I have uploaded various versions of the application on 8 June, 13 July etc and I was able to do above said changes during this period.

Answer (score 1):

change previous version code in current app and sign again and publish your application in market.by this way you can allow people to use old version.